# How to get a Linux container to connect to the internet through a bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, bridge, lxc

My Linux host has a bridge device `br0`, and I have created an arch Linux container but it isn't able to access the internet.

When the container is started the veth device appears on the host:

```
[host]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:d4:35:70:0b:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::76d4:35ff:fe70:b2f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be:b3:74:db:60:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:d4:35:70:0b:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.44/24 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::76d4:35ff:fe70:b2f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
37: veth2G6SCA@if36: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:5d:8a:48:81:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 169.254.192.90/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute veth2G6SCA
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fc5d:8aff:fe48:8174/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and the following routes (with `***` next to them) appear:

```
[host]# ip route
default via 192.168.1.254 dev br0 proto static 
default dev veth2G6SCA scope link src 169.254.192.90 metric 237 ***
169.254.0.0/16 dev veth2G6SCA scope link src 169.254.192.90 metric 237 ***
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.44
```

Inside the container

```
[container]# ip addr
38: eth0@if39: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:86:c2:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe86:c29f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[container]# ip route
```

The container isn't able to ping ip addresses or domains.

systemctl shows networkd and resolved failed:

```
[container]# systemctl
...
● systemd-networkd.service          loaded failed failed    Network Service                                                              
● systemd-resolved.service          loaded failed failed    Network Name Resolution
```

Using `journalctl -r` I could find some errors but I didn't understand them.

```
Feb 03 20:04:53 archie systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
Feb 03 20:04:53 archie systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 03 20:04:53 archie systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Service has no hold-off time (RestartSec=0), scheduling restart.
Feb 03 20:04:53 archie systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Service.
Feb 03 20:04:53 archie systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 03 20:04:53 archie systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Feb 03 20:04:53 archie systemd[29]: systemd-networkd.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd: Permission>
Feb 03 20:04:53 archie systemd[29]: systemd-networkd.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: Permission denied
Feb 03 20:04:53 archie systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
```

I looked up that 169.254 ip addresses are a result of failed DHCP.

I tried to edit the systemd-networkd config file in the container to use a static IP address like the example from here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd#Usage_with_containers

```
[container]# cat /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.77/24
Gateway=192.168.1.254
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

but networking still does not work and the same errors occur.

> How can I get networking to work inside the container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to make this run using opensvc agent managing my lxc containers.

Please find below a sample service configuration :

```
[DEFAULT]
nodes = {clusternodes}
encapnodes = {container#1.name}
nodes@encapnodes = {container#1.name}

[disk#1]
type = zpool
name = {env.zfspool}
scsireserv = true
shared = true

[fs#root]
dev = {env.zfspool}
mnt = /srv/{svcname}
type = zfs
shared = true

[fs#container]
dev = {env.zfspool}/rootfs
mnt = {fs#root.mnt}/rootfs
type = zfs
shared = true

[container#1]
name = {env.lxcname}
type = lxc
rootfs = {fs#container.mnt}
shared = true

[ip#1]
type = netns
ipdev = {env.ipdev}
ipname = {env.ipname}
netmask = {env.netmask}
gateway = {env.gateway}
netns = container#1
shared = true

[env]
zfspool = {svcname}
lxcname = {svcname}
ipdev = br0
ipname = lxc.acme.com
netmask = 24
gateway = 10.11.12.1
```

As you can see in the `ip#1` section, there is a reference to `container#1` section; it means that when the opensvc service will start, the opensvc agent will inject the ip configuration into the container referenced.

`{svcname}` is a reference to the actual opensvc service name.